# how to use run two processes on visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am writing a game in XNA, and I have the login screen, which is windows form, and the game itself. I need to go from the login screen to the game, but when I try it says that i can't run more then one thred at the time. how can i solve this?
this is the login screen code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProtoType
{
    public partial class SighIn : Form
    {
        public SighIn()
     {
        InitializeComponent();

     }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((textBox1.Text.Equals("Developer")) && (textBox2.Text.Equals("poxus17")))
        {
            using (Game1 game = new Game1())
            {                  
                game.Run();
            }

        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the namespace System.Threading is a good start

Answer (score 0):

The XNA Game.Run method executes Application.Run which provides a message pump for the primary thread (UI thread).

At the point in time where your form is running and gets a button click, Application.Run is already executing (possibly through Form.ShowDialog). You cannot have two message pumps in the same thread, at the same time.

The solution is to allow Application.Run to finish, then call Game.Run.

Something like this:

```
Form form = new SignIn();
if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    if (form.UserName =="Developer" && form.Password == "poxus17")
    {
        using (Game1 game = new Game1())
        {
            game.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Now your form's button click handler can copy the textbox fields to properties (UserName, and Password) and set this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK. This will close the form, completing the message pump started by ShowDialog, then, after verification, start a new message pump with Game.Run.

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work. in case it wasn't clear i use application.run to activate the program, not showDialog(), because that causes problems.

Comment: @user3439131 Did you replace the content of Program.Main (or wherever your main is)?